# Magento 1.9 - How to add serial number in sales orders list & invoice list?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, invoice, column, serialize

How to add serial number for both order list and invoice list,

sales->order

[image]

sales->order->invoice

[image]

If i add below code in ->

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\items.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     default_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<div class="grid np">
  <div class="hor-scroll">
    <table cellspacing="0" class="data order-tables">
        <col width="1">
        <col />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SNo.') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Product') ?></th>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Item Status') ?></span></th>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Original Price') ?></span></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Price') ?></th>
                <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Qty') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Tax Amount') ?></span></th>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Tax Percent') ?></span></th>
                <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Discount Amount') ?></span></th>
                <th class="last"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Row Total') ?></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php $_items = $this->getItemsCollection() ?>
        <?php $i=0;foreach ($_items as $_item):?>
            <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++;?>
            <tbody class="<?php echo $i%2?'even':'odd' ?>">
                <?php echo $i ?>
                <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php echo $this->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item) ?>
            </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
```

align mismatch,

Screenshot :

[image]

Any help to solve the alignment error, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please follow below step to add SR No into Sales order items list.

Open

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml
```

file and replace with below code.

```
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<div class="grid np">
 <div class="hor-scroll">
  <table cellspacing="0" class="data order-tables">
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <thead>
        <tr class="headings">

            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SR No.') ?></span></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Product') ?></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Item Status') ?></span></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Original Price') ?></span></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Price') ?></th>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Tax Amount') ?></span></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Tax Percent') ?></span></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Discount Amount') ?></span></th>
            <th class="last"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Row Total') ?></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php $_items = $this->getItemsCollection() ?>
    <?php $i=0;foreach ($_items as $_item):?>
        <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++;?>
        <tbody class="<?php echo $i%2?'even':'odd' ?>">
            <tr class="border">
                <td class="a-center"><?php echo $i; ?> </td>
                <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php echo $this->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item) ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Then open

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

> - Remove line no 29 `<tr<?php if (!$this->canDisplayGiftmessage()): ?> class="border"<?php endif; ?>>`
> - Remove line no 246 `</tr>`

[image]

Please follow below step to add SR No into Sales order invoice items list.

Open

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/view/items.phtml
```

***file and replace with below code from line no 27 to line no 73.***

```
<div class="grid np">
 <div class="hor-scroll">
  <table cellspacing="0" class="data order-tables">
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
            <th><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('SR No.') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Product') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Price') ?></th>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Tax Amount') ?></span></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Discount Amount') ?></span></th>
            <th class="last"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Row Total') ?></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php $_items = $this->getInvoice()->getAllItems() ?>
    <?php $i=0;foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
        <?php if ($_item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++; ?>
        <tbody class="<?php echo $i%2?'even':'odd' ?>">
            <tr class="border">
                <td><?php echo $i; ?> </td>
                <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php echo $this->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item->getOrderItem()) ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Then open

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

> - Remove line no 30 `<tr class="border">`
> - Remove line no 233 `</tr>`

[image]